# How to pass arrays and nested arrays from Controller to Javascript in View in Yii framework

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, yii

I have some array in my Controller and some nested arrays inside which is result of query from database. I want to pass this data to javascript by AJAX and update content on site when I check the checkbox. Pls show me an example or give me some advice how to do it.

**Controller**

```
 public function actionTestResponse(){
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $checkval = $_POST['checkval'];
        $this->layout = 'newhome';
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
        if($id == 'checkFemale'){
            $criteria->compare('sex', 'female');
        } else if ($id == 'checkFemale'){
            $criteria->compare('sex', 'male');
        }

        $items = User::model()->findAll($criteria);


        //if($items==null||empty($items)){$items='NULL';}
        //$response = array('id'=>$id, 'checkval'=>$checkval, array('data' => $items));
        $response = array('id'=>$id, 'checkval'=>$checkval);
        //$data = array('data'=>$items);
        //$result = array_merge($response, $data);
        //var_dump($result);
        //die;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

**View**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkFemale" class="checktest">Female
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".checktest").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                var checkval = 1;
            } else
            {
                var checkval = 0;
            }
            var string = 'id='+ id + '&checkval='+ checkval;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testResponse",
                data: string,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.checkval == 1)
                    {
                        $("#"+response.id).prop('checked', true);
                    } else
                    {
                        $("#"+response.id).removeAttr('checked');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Example of array**

```
array(3) { ["id"]=> checkFemale ["checkval"]=> 0 ["data"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(User)#60 (11) { ["_new":"CActiveRecord":private]=> bool(false) ["_attributes":"CActiveRecord":private]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["user_id"]=> int(46) ["sex"]=> string(6) "female" ["certificate"]=> int(1) ["date_added"]=> string(10) "2015-02-02" ["date_of_birth"]=> string(10) "2015-01-01" } ["_related":"CActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_c":"CActiveRecord":private]=> NULL ["_pk":"CActiveRecord":private]=> int(1) ["_alias":"CActiveRecord":private]=> string(1) "t" ["_errors":"CModel":private]=> array(0) { } ["_validators":"CModel":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"CModel":private]=> string(6) "update" ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } [1]=> object(User)#61 (11) { ["_new":"CActiveRecord":private]=> bool(false) ["_attributes":"CActiveRecord":private]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["user_id"]=> int(53) ["sex"]=> string(4) "male" ["certificate"]=> int(0) ["date_added"]=> string(10) "2015-02-02" ["date_of_birth"]=> string(10) "2013-06-08" } ["_related":"CActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_c":"CActiveRecord":private]=> NULL ["_pk":"CActiveRecord":private]=> int(3) ["_alias":"CActiveRecord":private]=> string(1) "t" ["_errors":"CModel":private]=> array(0) { } ["_validators":"CModel":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"CModel":private]=> string(6) "update" ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } } }
```

Comment: Try to format $items and then access it in javascript CJSON::decode(CJSON::encode($items));

Comment: is the ajax currently working as it is

Comment: no... it is working only when I give to echo $response... But I need to send more information... much more (query of selected rows from database)

Comment: this is problem that i wanted to ask... How can I pass array like this... or how to do it. I dont know... AJAX is working when I send for example data like this  `array('id'=>$id, 'checkval'=>$checkval, 'variable'=>$variable, 'variable2'=>$variable2, 'variable3'=>$variable3);` but how can I send array and nested array?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Here is the solution. Thank you for your comments.

**Controller**

```
public function actionTestResponse(){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $checkval = $_POST['checkval'];
    $this->layout = 'newhome';
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria();
    if($id == 'checkFemale'){
        $criteria->compare('sex', 'female');
    } else if ($id == 'checkFemale'){
        $criteria->compare('sex', 'male');
    }

    $items = User::model()->findAll($criteria);

    $list = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $list[] = array(
            'id'  => $item->id,
            'sex' => $item->sex,
        );
    }
    $result = array('id'=>$id, 'checkval'=>$checkval, 'data' => $list);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**View**

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "testResponse",
    data: string,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        $.each(response, function (item, value) {
            if(item=="checkval"){
                if(value == 1){
                    $("#"+response.id).prop('checked', true);
                } else {
                    $("#"+response.id).removeAttr('checked');
                }
            }
            else if(item=="data"){
                $.each(value, function (i, v) {
                    $.each(v, function (it, va) {
                        console.log(it);
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```